# Undefined reference to ... when linking a static library in C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, linker, static-libraries

I'm implementing an AVL-tree as part of a library and can't figure out whether it is CppUnit, NetBeans 8, my C++ skills (templates) or something else that is the problem, but the code compiles as a static library but when used together with CppUnit or a standalone application I get `undefined reference to MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<int, char>::function`.

I've reduced the code as much as possible while still maintaining the same error.

AVLTree.h

```
namespace MyProject {
    namespace Utilities {
        template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> class AVLTree {
        public:
            AVLTree();
            AVLTree(const MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>& orig);
            virtual ~AVLTree();
            bool hasRoot() const;
            MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* getRoot() const;

        protected:
            void setRoot(MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* _node);

        private:
            MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* _root;
            unsigned int _size;

        };
    };
};
```

AVLTree.cpp

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::AVLTree() {
    this->setRoot(NULL);
    this->_size = 0;
}

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::AVLTree(const MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>& orig) {
    this->setRoot(orig.getRoot());
    this->_size = orig.size();
}

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::~AVLTree() {
    // this->clear();
}

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> void MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::setRoot(MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* _root) {
    this->_root = _root;
}

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> bool MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::hasRoot() const {
    return this->getRoot() != NULL;
}

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::getRoot() const {
    return this->_root;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "AVLTree.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<int, char> instance;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        instance.hasRoot();
        // instance.insert(i, (char) (65 + i));
    }

    //instance.graphviz("./test.dot");
    return 0;
}
```

The following error is returned by Netbeans 8 when attempting to build cppapplication_1

```
g++    -c -g -I../../Documents/MyProject/src/header -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L../../Documents/MyProject/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86 -lmyproject
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
/home/.../CppApplication_1/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<int, char>::AVLTree()'
/home/.../CppApplication_1/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<int, char>::hasRoot() const'
/home/.../CppApplication_1/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<int, char>::~AVLTree()'
/home/.../CppApplication_1/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<int, char>::~AVLTree()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

.

.

.

.

.

.

The code below produces about 100 errors of varying content... I don't mean to be daft but for the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong, nor can I find a working example or tutorial to work with...

```
src/header/AVLTree.h:16:23: error: declaration of ‘class KeyType’
         template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> AVLTree();
src/header/AVLTree.h:14:19: error:  shadows template parm ‘class KeyType’
     template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> class AVLTree {
src/header/AVLTree.h:16:41: error: declaration of ‘class ValueType’
         template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> AVLTree();
src/header/AVLTree.h:14:37: error:  shadows template parm ‘class ValueType’
     template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> class AVLTree {
In file included from src/AVLTree.cpp:1:0:
src/header/AVLTree.h:18:23: error: declaration of ‘class KeyType’
         template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> virtual ~AVLTree();
```

AVLTree.h

```
namespace MyProject {

    namespace Utilities {

        template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> class AVLTree {
        public:
            template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> AVLTree();
            template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> AVLTree(const MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>& orig);
            template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> virtual ~AVLTree();
            template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> bool hasRoot() const;
            template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* getRoot() const;

        protected:
            void setRoot(MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* _node);

        private:
            MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* _root;

        };
    };
};
```

AVLTree.cpp (with types specified)

```
MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::AVLTree() {
    this->setRoot(NULL);
}

MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::AVLTree(const MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>& orig) {
    this->setRoot(orig.getRoot());
    // this->_size = orig.size();
}

MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::~AVLTree() {
    // this->clear();
}

void MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::setRoot(MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* _root) {
    this->_root = _root;
}

bool MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::hasRoot() const {
    return this->getRoot() != NULL;
}

MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<KeyType, ValueType>::getRoot() const {
    return this->_root;
}
```

AVLTree.cpp (with types unspecified)

```
MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree::AVLTree() {
    this->setRoot(NULL);
}

MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree::AVLTree(const MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree& orig) {
    this->setRoot(orig.getRoot());
    // this->_size = orig.size();
}

MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree::~AVLTree() {
    // this->clear();
}

void MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree::setRoot(MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* _root) {
    this->_root = _root;
}

bool MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree::hasRoot() const {
    return this->getRoot() != NULL;
}

MyProject::Utilities::AVLNode<KeyType, ValueType>* MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree::getRoot() const {
    return this->_root;
}
```

Comment: Building a static library will not reveal missing symbols, since no linking occurs. Also, you need to either have your AVLTree template's function definitions in the header file so they are available for instantiation or you need to explicitly instantiate all instances that will be needed by external code in the cpp file.

Comment: @heinrichj I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean I doing wrong with the templates and function definitions, could you please provide an example in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are not functions. They don't exist in code. They are just sort of blueprints, or instructions on how to actually make a function once all template parameters are known. Because of this all templates must reside in header files, to be visible once all template parameters are known. <strike>Move all template code from AVLTree.cpp to AVLTree.h</strike>. Not enough to just move, must also change it.

Here is an example that compiles on my Visual Studio:

```
namespace My {
    namespace Util {
        template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> class World {
        public:
            World()
            {
            }

            World(const My::Util::World<KeyType, ValueType>& orig)
            {
            }

            virtual ~World()
            {
            }

            bool Hello() const
            {
                return true;
            }
        };
    };
};
```

Use the code like this:

```
My::Util::World<int, char> world;
world.Hello();
```

It is possible to separate all functions from class declaration, but it serves no practical purpose, because all that separated code must be visible anyway. It would look something like this:

```
namespace My {
    namespace Util {
        template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType> class World {
            ....
            bool Hello() const;
        };
    };
};

template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
bool My::Util::World<KeyType, ValueType>::Hello() const
{
    return true;
}
```

I tried your example, and it works for me. I just placed all function templates just after class template, and commented out all code that deals with `AVLNode`, and it compiled. So my original statement appears to be valid: just move all template code from source to header. Your second example code is different from your first. All you should have done is move.

Comment: There's obviously something I'm not understanding with templates, but I really can't understand how the template code could be moved from the implementation of functions without generating millions of "KeyType/ValueType/AVLTree/AVLNode unknown" errors.. I haven't found tutorials where code is separated, but in this one for example (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html) template syntax is adjacent to the implementation

Comment: @JohnSmith like I said, templates (be they function templates or class templates) are just "ideas". They don't exist as functions or classes. Only when you instantiate a template (eg. `MyProject::Utilities::AVLTree<int, char>`) only there compiler knows how to churn up the code for the class `AVLTree<int, char>` and all its member functions. But compiler needs to "see" all those function templates, and it can only "see" them if they are included from header file.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I can't seem to find an example which illustrate how this is done. Even IBMs quite extensive C++ guide uses the template keyword for implementation, not definition (https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclass_templates.htm).

If you could *please* provide a hello world, or sum, example that is separated into two files I'd be greatful.

Comment: @John my example would look exactly like your code, but with all the template code from AVLTree.cpp moved to AVLTree.h. You seem to be confused with how compiler sees header files. Compiler does not see header files, because header files are "inserted" into source file during [preprocessing phase](http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/c/PreprocessCompileLink.htm). Compiler works only with one stream of code text.

Comment: *Please* see my edited (updated) post, I realize that I have a high-school level problem but I've been stuck with it all day and can't figure out additional search terms that will result in articles I haven't already read...

Comment: @John I apologize for not checking your code more carefully. I updated the answer.